# Import Error When Trying to Run Bot

Tags: python, irc, pip

Recently upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 and now I get this error when I try to run the irc bot sopel:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/sopel", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('sopel==6.0.0a4', 'console_scripts', 'sopel')()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 521, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2632, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2312, in load
return self.resolve()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2318, in resolve
module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ImportError: No module named run_script
```

Apologies in advance if this question is stupid - I'm a beginner, but I managed to get willie (previous version of sopel) working under the last OS I was using. Figures that I'd have my host rebuild my VPS only to somehow forget how to get an irc bot running lol.

Comment: Edited: This is not a pip but an import error. It could be caused by pip installation of course but it could not.